# Is it safe to use a 4-digit PIN for Android system encryption?

Tags: encryption, passwords, android

I just encrypted my Android phone using the default menu.
I was asked for a PIN code (4 digits).
Do you think this is a good practice? Is there a limited number of attempts at decrypting the filesystem?

What if an attacker dumps the data and tries every combination from 0000 to 9999? (That should be possible in less than a few seconds).

Comment: "dumping the data" will be difficult when the device is encrypted. In some Android devices, the minimum is 6 digits with a mix of letters and numbers.

Comment: I don't think it would be hard to dump ENCRYPTED data, such as full partitions.

Answer (score 4):

How secure this is will depend on a number of factors.

- Do you have device wipe enabled on incorrect guesses.  Assuming that you have the device set to wipe after 10 incorrect PIN guesses then without any clues and a purely random PIN, an attacker has a 1/1000 shot at guessing it.  Of course most users base PINs on things like dates or years which cuts the keyspace down a bit.
- For offline brute-force, it depends on how the encryption is implemented.  If it's purely software (as older android versions are) then obviously there's a risk that if the attacker can dump the filesystem they can brute-force the key. In newer Android devices, there is a hardware element which stores part of the encryption key, making that basic offline attack impractical, without further weaknesses.

In general I'd recommend upping the PIN length to at least 6 numeric characters and don't choose something obvious (like a date of birth).  If you're very concerned about security consider using an alpha-numeric password (although this is generally horrible from a usuability perspective) and / or make sure your device implements the encryption in hardware to reduce the risk of offline attacks.